# Xvnc and Wayland session running in paralel: How to force terminal launch in Xvnc

Tags: vnc, wayland, d-bus

Context:
I have three laptops. One with Windows, another one with Mac and finally one with Fedora.
I want to continue using my Fedora destkop when on Windows/Mac, so I start an Tiger VNC server on Fedora, and I connect to it both from Fedora Wayland, Windows and Mac OSX.

Problem: Some times when the Wayland session is active and I launch a new terminal or Firefox program it launches in the active wayland session (vs the XVnc desktop).
I tried exporting the DISPLAY variable pointing to the correct Xvnc session, but it looks to be ignored. Then I tried launching terminator with the option "-u" to ignore dbus, but it doesn't look to work either. Then I tried also killing the user dbus process, with no success. Finally I unset all the enviroment variables related to DBUS. No luck yet.

I really completely ignore what is the launch flow or logic that desktop applications are using today to choose where they want to be "rendered". (A old xterm is launched in the expected VNC Server for example with no tuning at all).

Comment: I could "dodge" or "patch" the problem by creating a guest user and use it to log into my Wayland desktop. No idea yet how to fix it using just a single user (maybe actually it's better to isolate using standard Unix/Linux users).